# how to compile a gem without compiler hardening in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ruby, makefile, rubygems, swig

I am using [a gem](https://github.com/vydao/ztx) that won't compile on Ubuntu because of what appears are compiler hardening settings.

If I clone the gem's repo and modify the Makefile to add a CPPFLAG of `-Wno-format-security` then it compiles just fine.

My problem is that when I try to install that gem with `gem install ztx-0.0.1.gem` it tries to compile the gem again but somehow ignoring the CPP flags specified of the Makefile. (I assume this is happening because I get the same errors that I was getting before adding the `-Wno-format-security` flag).

I tried exporting CPPFLAGS before calling `gem install...` but with the same results.

So, my question is, how can I force those CPP flags so that I can compile that gem?

Comment: "-Wno-format-security" - why would you do that?

Comment: Are you getting warnings, or errors, @edmz? `-Wno-format-security` shoudn't cause compilation to fail, since it just enables warnings.

Comment: @Joe, some distributions compile everything with `-Werror=format-security`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know I should not. But this is a gem that I've been using for years. I still haven't decided if I am going to keep using it but now I just want to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Joe I think I am getting errors:  

    `tx_swig_wrap.cxx:4369:41: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem although the solution is not a direct answer to this question.

I wanted to disable the compiler errors caused by the compiler hardening settings in ubuntu. As @Jesper pointed out in the comments that might not be a wise idea.

But I wanted to know why it wasn't working. It compiled fine on MacOS. Then I noticed that most of the errors were in a file called `tx_swig_wrap.cxx`.

I know very little about swig, but I kind of new that it allows some c/c++ code to be called from ruby, python, etc.

It was then that I realized that maybe that wrapper file was generated by swig and that the errors I was getting might have been fixed by a newer swig version.

The wrapper file has a comment section at the top that tells you the swig version that created it. It was 1.X and the latest swig is v3.X.

I installed swig and I learned that I could regenerate the wrapper by executing `swig -c++ -ruby tx_swig.i`.

I did just that and with the new generated file the gem compiled without issues.